# Files with long filenames appear as empty

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, bash, powershell, notepad++

*I'm not too familiar with Windows, so please bear with me.*

I have a folder with several files with very long filenames, that can be listed normally, but if I try to open them with any Windows application they appear as empty (tried Atom, VS Code, Notepad++, and Chrome via file:///).

If I cat them from the terminal (both Git Bash and Powershell) they can be displayed no problem.

Moving the directory upwards, so that the full path is shorter, fixed the problem.

I'm extremely puzzled about why this happens. At the very least I expected some sort of "filename too long" exception, certainly I didn't expect them to pretend to work and just appear empty.

So here's the question: **is this expected/known behaviour**? Or maybe there could be something that is breaking everything? (like, I don't know, an Antivirus that doesn't support long names, even if the apps would).

Please notice that at least one of the apps (Atom) is compiled for 64bits, in case it matters.

Comment: You need Windows 10 1607 and the program developer has to activate it within the program: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later For Notepad++ there an issue asking to support it: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4078

Comment: You can also refer to odd-ball filenames with the 8.3 format or with wild cards. E.G. to open "C:VeryLong...FolderName\AnotherLongFolderName...\VeryLongPFilename.txt" from CMD, "cd Ver*", then "cd Ano*", finally "type ver*".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes, it worked that way, but it is useless for me, since I need to be able to navigate them, and if I try to navigate, I automatically get the longer names.

Comment: I am going to assume that you've already done this. ['windows 10 enable long filename'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27windows%2010%20enable%20long%20file%20name%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27windows%2010%20enable%20long%20file%20name%27&sc=3-34&sk=&cvid=26DE2FC005EA40D89038D4CC69E915EE), and thus eliminated this as a potential root cause?

Comment: @postanote yes I did check it after comment 1, and it was already enabled.